Redirecting to different routes according to user type
This is my express code, I'm handling authentication by passport.js and passport-local-mongoose, I've been having trouble redirecting different user type to their dashboard
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const userModel = require("./users");
const passport = require("passport");
const localStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const session = require("express-session");

passport.use(new localStrategy(userModel.authenticate()));
/* GET home page. */

router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("intro");
});

router.get("/aboutus", (req, res) => {
  res.render("aboutus");
});

router.get("/auth", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login");
});

const checkUserType = (req, res, next) => {
  const userType = req.user;
  console.log(userType);
  if (req.isAuthenticated() && userType === "doctor") {
    const obj1 = {
      successRedirect: "/doctorProfile",
      failureRedirect: "/auth",
      failureMessage: true,
    };
    return obj1;
  } else {
    const obj2 = {
      successRedirect: "/patientProfile",
      failureRedirect: "/auth",
      failureMessage: true,
    };
    return obj2;
  }
};

router.get("/doctorProfile", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  res.render("doctor");
});

router.get("/patientProfile", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  res.render("patientProfile");
});

router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  var userData = new userModel({
    name: req.body.name,
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    user_type: req.body.user_type,
  });
  userModel.register(userData, req.body.password).then(() => {
    console.log("You have registered");
    res.redirect("/auth");
  });
});

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect("/auth");
}

router.post(
  "/signin",
  passport.authenticate("local", checkUserType),
  (req, res) => {}
);

module.exports = router;


I'm passing the checkUserType middleware to passport.authenticate. The error I am facing is when I try to console.log(req.user.user_type) it prints undefined. I don't know what to do?
